# using non-clr dll on C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, clr

I'm using licensed library(c++ dll) for developing c# application.

I don't have any codes of that library, and that's not clr.

but I can import its methods on c# by using pInvoke like below.

```
[DllImport("FaceFinding.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
unsafe internal static extern int EnrollmentGalleryDBOneToOne(StringBuilder currentFolderPath);
```

It works perfectly on debug mode.

but here's problem.

when I make Visual studio Installer project, I cannot import that dll file on installer because that's non-clr.

is there some way to import non-clr dll on c# installer project?

Comment: are you including it in your installer?

Comment: @DanielA.White I can include it, but just file. not assembly. It doesn't work on program installed.

Comment: If you need to DllImport the DLL, it's an *unmanaged* DLL, therefor it will never be an 'assembly' in the .NET sense. If your program doesn't work it's for a different reason, try debugging it after installation

Comment: It is just a file that needs to be copied, that's all.  Do use the owner's install instructions, there might be additional dependencies that need to be present, like the C/C++ runtime support DLLs.  If you are not sure then contact him for support, you are paying for it.  Do insist on an MSI merge module, a very reasonable request.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your unmanaged DLL's (including FaceFinding.dll) in the output folder, in the File System editor of your installer project. This way they will be published along with your application.

As a side note I would also suggest making sure that the license of this 3rd party DLL allows you to distribute it with your application by examining its license agreement.

Comment: thanks for answering. when I put all DLL in output folder, CLR DLLs added as Assembly, but non-clr DLL added as File. so it doesn't work after installing.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by added as assembly or added as a file? you just need the file to be at a known location to use pInvoke. By putting it in the output folder it's next to your executable, which makes you current code work as is