# Setting up a mixed C# and C++ project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I want to create a Windows application using a C# GUI that calls some C++ code but I have troubles setting up the project in Visual Studio.
I understood that I have to do it the following way : 3 projects (the C++ project, the C# project and a wrapper CLR project) that are linked to each others in some way. I just can't figure out how the link works.

If anyone can explain me in details what I have to do, I'd be really happy :3

Otherwise, I can use a Github link of a project already set up that I could copy.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will take some time to answer.

Comment: [https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/542614/Howplustopluscallplusaplusc-2b-2bplusdllplusinplus](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/542614/Howplustopluscallplusaplusc-2b-2bplusdllplusinplus)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160461/using-non-clr-dll-on-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160461/using-non-clr-dll-on-c-sharp)